# Grails / Shiro internal URL request

Tags: grails, shiro

We have a grails app and are using the Shiro security plugin.

We are currently using the groovy URL feature to grab the output of a page and render the contents within a DIV but when such a request is made to any of the protected Shiro pages, it presents to us the login page as Shiro does not recognise the internal request as a valid logged in user.

Does anybody have any idea how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean with "URL feature" something like

```
def output = new URL("http://google.com").text
```

this is an external request - that's the reason for the login page.

Use the `g.render`-method instead http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html to fetch your internal content:

```
String output = render(template:'/book/form',model:[book:myBook])
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html